# Change all Columns data to Upper Case in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The below statement returns all field names that can be string values.  I need to now change each fields data to uppercase.

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') AND table_name = 'plats';
```

here is the update statement.

```
Update Plats
 set col1 = UPPER(col1)
```

how do I get col1 to become the list from the first statement, so it will run all columns at once instead of me changing the name each time.

Comment: I'd personally advise to use the catalog views in SQL Server over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, there are a number of reasons for this ([described here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)), but the most pertinent one in this case is that there is no way to identify a computed column using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, so you may end up attempting to update a computed column which will fail. These are identifiable in `sys.columns` with the `is_computed` field, so you can exclude these from the update.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a one shot action, you may do

```
select 'update ' + table_name + ' set ' + column_name + ' = UPPPER(' + column_name + ');')
from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') AND table_name = 'plats';
```

execute this in your dbms administrator tool (ssms probably), copy/paste the result and execute it.

Else, you'll need a stored procedure with dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'update ' + table_name + ' set ' + column_name + '= upper(' + column_name + ');'
from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') 
  AND table_name = 'plats';
```

This query should return the update statements you want. The result should be executed as SQL statements. I don't think this can be done in one single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using a group concat type query like so will produce a single update statement

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @qry = 'UPDATE plats SET' + STUFF(CAST((
    SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = UPER(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ')'
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar') AND table_name = 'plats'
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @qry
-- EXEC(@qry)
```